# Rider Hot Reload for .NET Core WebApi not working

Tags: ide, jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

So basically If I make a code change, the C# application won't restart, I had to rerun manually the build project everytime I add a new line of code. This is on JetBrains Rider IDE.

So as they say in [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Hot_Reload.html#Apply_changes_with_a_keyboard_shortcut), this feature is enable by default if I'm using .NET Core 6+ (which I do), I also have all checks
[image: Configuration of Rider]

Any ideas so far? Or am I missing something and I need to rerun everytime I change something on the Controller with this IDE?

Comment: Which version of Rider are you using? And which kind of file do you change? Maybe a little GIF would make it easier to see what's happening on your side

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, basically I'm building a webapi, with controllers, entities, etc. Everytime I make a code change in any of those files, I need to rerun the app

Comment: Idk why but I saw in some random YouTube video that you can now with the hot reload, make change in any file and the application will rebuild by itself, but that's not my case but Idk if that's even possible, I come from Python & JavaScript where that's pretty easy

Comment: Python and JavaScript have an interpreter, not a compiler, so let's not compare different things  I don't have any problems with Hot Reload, it just works. Maybe you can create a new Web API project from scratch? Or you create a GitHub repo based on your code and share it here so that I can have a look

Comment: Lol? I'm not even comparing Python/JavaScript to C# smart guy, I'm just switched jobs and I have the requirement to use .NET Framework, I know from some research that this lenguage needs to be compiled everytime, but as I SAID I saw some random guy who was able to every Ctrl + S to rebuild his web api everytime lol

Comment: And also before you say something, I know Hot Reload is from .NET Core 6 (latest version which I have) and still can't figure this out, created a project with default settings and hot reload only works for normal code like Write.Console, etc, but when it comes to rebuild an controller/service it doesn't work

Comment: Idk if this repo really helps but this is the repo in case you need it https://github.com/874anthony/dating-app-netcore